# BitBucket - Create repository and sub modules

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-add, bitbucket-server

I am using **bitbucket** web interface and have created a new project "Test_Project".
In this project, I am able to create a new repository - 'Module1' using **Create repository** option.

Now I want to create repository hierarchy in bitbucket project - Test_Project as following :-

Test_Project (Bitbucket project)

- Web (Repository 1)

  ```
   Module1 (Sub-Repository/Sub-module 1)
   Module2 (Sub-Repository/Sub-module 2)
   Module3 (Sub-Repository/Sub-module 3)
  ```
- Mobile (Repository 2)

  ```
   Module1 (Sub-Repository/Sub-module 1)
   Module2 (Sub-Repository/Sub-module 2)
   Module3 (Sub-Repository/Sub-module 3)
  ```
- Archive (Repository 3)

  ```
   Module1 (Sub-Repository/Sub-module 1)
   Module2 (Sub-Repository/Sub-module 2)
   Module3 (Sub-Repository/Sub-module 3)
  ```
- Project Documents (Repository 4)

  And so on..

So that I will add the local projects in respective bitbucket sub repositories

Can anyone please guide how to create the sub-repositories/sub-modules in new repository in bitbucket.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Now, I am able to create Bitbucket Repository Structure with sub-repository/sub-folders.

Please follow these steps:-

1. Create a new Repository in Bitbucket project.
2. To interact with your new repository, you'll need to clone this repository to your local machine using a git client.
   I am using ‘SourceTree’ as a GIT client (another Atlassian product, integrates well with Bitbucket, you can use a "Clone To SourceTree" button in Bitbucket to make things easier).
3. Once you have a local repository, copy/move your project into it , and use your chosen tool to add/commit the files and push them to bitbucket.

Thanks,

Jatin

Answer (score 16):

You simply need to be in your root folder and then add the submodule folder.

```
git submodule add <url>
```

Now when you clone the project you simply need to init and update the submodule

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Git 1.8.2 features a new option --remote

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

will fetch the latest changes from upstream in each submodule, merge them in, and check out the latest revision of the submodule. As [the docs](https://github.com/blog/2131-git-2-8-has-been-released) put it:

> ***`--remote`***
>
> This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch.

This is equivalent to running git pull in each submodule.

---

#### ***[`Git 2.8 update`](https://github.com/blog/2131-git-2-8-has-been-released)***

> ***Parallel fetches of submodules***
>
> Using `git submodules`, one Git repository can include other Git repositories as subdirectories1. This can be a useful way to include libraries or other external dependencies into your main project. The top-level repository specifies which submodules it wants to include, and which version of each submodule.
>
> When you fetch into the top-level repository, you typically want to fetch into the submodule repositories as well:
>
> ```
> git fetch --recurse-submodules
> ```
>
> If you have a lot of submodules, all of these fetches can be time-consuming; git fetch is essentially run in each submodule in turn.
>
> But now you can speed things up by fetching from multiple submodules in parallel. For example,
>
> ```
> git fetch --recurse-submodules --jobs=4
> ```

Comment: Hi, I am able to add submodule folder in my local root folder by using **git submodule add <url>**
Now I want to push this local root folder containing sub-modules on Bitbucket server but I am unable to do it. While pushing, it gives message as following:-

$ git push -u origin --all
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date

Please guide how to create and push  the sub-repositories/sub-modules in new repository in bitbucket.